# Laravel collection how to remove a specific key from all items?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

It sounded crazy simple to me at first but I can't find the solution!

Here is My collection :

```
Collection {#433
  #items: array:432 [
    0 => array:5 [
      "word_id" => 12218
      "name" => "ordered"
      "rank" => 12217
      "is_real" => 1
      "id" => 1
    ]
    1 => array:5 [
      "word_id" => 12097
      "name" => "one-dimensional"
      "rank" => 12096
      "is_real" => 1
      "id" => 2
    ]
    2 => array:5 [
      "word_id" => 19679
      "name" => "watery"
      "rank" => 19678
      "is_real" => 1
      "id" => 3
    ]
    .
    .
    .
```

But I want it to be like this :

```
Collection {#433 
  #items: array:432 [
    0 => array:5 [
      "name" => "ordered"
      "id" => 1
    ]
    1 => array:5 [
      "name" => "one-dimensional"
      "id" => 2
    ]
    2 => array:5 [
      "name" => "watery"
      "id" => 3
    ]
    .
    .
    .
```

How can it be done with laravel collection? Do I have to change my collection to array and do the manipulation myself? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$collection = $collection->map(function ($item) {
    return array_only($item, ['id', 'name']);
});
```

Comment: I have to wait 10 minutes to accept the answer,  Mentioned that because you didn't ask any questions till now, maybe you don't know this! 2,5 years without question?! WOWW!!!

Answer (score 5):

Or you can also use

```
 $collection = $collection ->map(function ($item) {
            return collect($item)->forget(['work_id','rank','is_real']);
        });
```

Comment: Don't post just code. Add some information to your answer tom improve the quality.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`only()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-only) method.

> The only method returns the items in the collection with the specified
> keys

```
$collection = $collection->map(function ($item) {
    return $item->only(['id', 'name'])
});
```

This way your collection still remains as collections;

> Please note, `only()` method is only available for Laravel collections
> not for an array

Comment: When i try it give an error `Call member function only() on array`

Comment: @PanjiSetyaNurPrawira, the `only()` method is only available for a collection, not for an array.
One thing you can do is to turn the array into a collection. e.g. $collection = collect($array_name);

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach could be to use the `Arr::only()` helper to reduce the items:

```
$collection = $collection->map(static fn($item) => Arr::only($item, ['id', 'name']));
```